# Is the size of T& the same as the size of T*?

Tags: c++

In C++, applying the `sizeof` operator to a reference type returns the size of the referenced type.

So, I wrote this wrapper class to get the size of the reference type itself:

```
template <typename T>
struct Ref {
    T& ref;
};
```

and I got that `sizeof(Ref<int>) == sizeof(int*)`; i.e. 4 bytes on a 32-bit architecture, and 8 bytes on a 64-bit architecture.

My questions are:

1. Is my assumption that `sizeof(Ref<T>)` is the actual size of `T&` correct?
2. If so, am I guaranteed that the size of `Ref<T>` (hence of `T&`) is the same as the size of `T*` for all types `T`?

Comment: `sizeof(Ref<T>)` gives you the size of class-type generated/instantiated from the class template.

Comment: @AnoopRana Since `T&` is the only (non-static) member variable, I'm assuming `sizeof(Ref<T>)` is the size of `T&`. If that's not the case, please let me know.

Comment: It might be different. Maybe the arch aligns all structs to 16 byte boundaries so the struct requires padding. Also why should the fact that they accidentally are the same size for the 2 systems you tested mean they should always be the same size?

Comment: NO. references have no inherent size of their own.  It isn't an independant variable. An implementation may implement them differently in different contexts. In some contexts the implementation might use a pointer. In other contexts it might not use any memory and be implicit in the generated assembly code. In yet other contexts, I haven't got a clue. There is NO independent, consistant size to find.

Comment: As example the compiler might represent pointers as {start, size, position} and do boundary checks while a reference always points to a single element and doesn't need that. So sizeof(T*) would be 24 and sizeof(Ref<T>) would be 8.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard actually does not specify this. Typically, references are implemented as pointers under the hood, so it is very likely that they have the same size. But again, as far as C++ standard doesn't specify this, we cannot be sure.